# What is the correct syntax for .group() in regex module

Tags: python, regex, expression

```
import re

phoneNumberRegex = re.compile(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')
mo = phoneNumberRegex.search('My number is 415-55-4242.')
print('Phone number found: ' + mo.group(0))
```

This is the method I have used tried to find some mistakes with the code all resulted in this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    print('Phone number found: ' + mo.group(0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: The result of you search was `None`, in other words: nothing was found. You have to handle that case, maybe with an `if` clause.

Comment: It won't find anything -- you need a capturing group: `(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})`

Comment: did you mean `\d{2,3}` ?

Comment: (r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\d') this was what I meant - format for lookup business numbers in a text.

Answer (score 3):

Usage of [`MatchObject.group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) is okay.

But, `415-55-4242` does not match `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}` because the middle part of the string contains only 2 digits.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}', 'My number is 415-55-4242.') # does not match => None
>>> re.search(r'\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}', 'My number is 415-55-4242.') # matches => MatchObject
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(13, 24), match='415-55-4242'>
```

To prevent the error, you need to guard the last statement:

```
phoneNumberRegex = re.compile(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')
mo = phoneNumberRegex.search('My number is 415-55-4242.')
if mo:
    print('Phone number found: ' + mo.group(0))
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to match `12345-123-12345`, you need to use word boundary (`\b`):

```
r'\b\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\b'
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I updated the answer to include it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It works -- group is the right method. However, you need a capturing group in you regex, and the regex is also a bit wrong. Use this code instead:

```
import re

phoneNumberRegex = re.compile(r'(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})')
mo = phoneNumberRegex.search('My number is 415-55-4242.')
print(mo.group(0))
```

Comment: This also works perfectly.  But what exactly is the capturing group.

Comment: @ragemon actually, that isn't needed, my bad. You can just remove the parentheses in the regex